# AS3 move sprite along predefined curve

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, draggable, flash-cs5, sprite

I want to make a circle(:Sprite) move along a pre-drawn curve. Using the graphics library a drew a 350 degree curve and I want my scrubber to move just from 0 degrees all tha way to 350 degrees without leaving the path. I found a great class from senocular.com that does this, but the problem is that Im limited to the lenght of the curve that I could use, since for it to work correctly I have to constrain myself to a maximum of a 90 degree curve. I also found another class that moves the sprite along a circle, but the problem with that is that once I reach the complete cycle. the sprite goes back to position 0. I just want the sprite to go from 0 - 350 and back, I dont want it to jump from 350 - 0. Is there any class or way to just draw the curve and attach the circle to that curve?
Here are some pics: 
 [image: Here is what senocular.com]
[image: Here is what I want]

Comment: There is a class that can do this, it's fl.motion.Animator or fl.motion.Motion, which Adobe Flash CS3+ use when you tell them to make a movieclip follow the path. Unfortunately, I don't have experience with them, and I don't know any libraries that do what you want out of the box. You can also make your own transition using fl.transition.Tween (or tweening libraries) tweening "rotation" from 0 to 350 and then back via Tween.yoyo().

Comment: Do you need to work with any arbitrary curve? or just circles?

Comment: @Cay well I have a 350 degree curve and a 90 degree curve

Comment: If it's only sections of a circle, you can use very simple math to move your objects along its path... 
 obj.x = centerx + Math.cos(angle/180*Math.PI)*radius;
 obj.y = centery + Math.sin(angle/180*Math.PI)*radius;
With that, you can just tween "angle" to the desired values. I'd recommend using some kind of tweening engine, like TweenLite or something similar.